# position of the drupal module inside the header

Tags: css, module, drupal-7, position

i m new to Drupal 7 and in this forum, please be nice :)

I m trying to customize a bit the drupal module "On the web" (that display facebook and youtube link button). This module work great but I would like to  to modify the position of the social images provided by this module inside a sub theme of Zen. I could be nice to put it at the left-top the header region.
 As it says in the documentation I :

1)

Place the following code in the template.php file in your theme, and replace 'mytheme' with the name of your theme:

```
    /**
    * Overrides theme_on_the_web_image().
    */
    function mytheme_on_the_web_image($variables) {
    return $variables['service'];
}
```

2) I add this line : `<div id="myidtomodifythecssafter"> <?php print $service; ?></div>` in the page.tpl.php like following :

```
<?php if ($site_name || $site_slogan): ?>
      <div id="name-and-slogan">
      <div id="myidtomodifythecssafter"> <?php print $service; ?></div>
        <?php if ($site_name): ?>
          <?php if ($title): ?>
            <div id="site-name"><strong>
              <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home"><span><?php print $site_name; ?></span></a>
            </strong></div>
          <?php else: /* Use h1 when the content title is empty */ ?>
            <h1 id="site-name">
              <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home"><span><?php print $site_name; ?></span></a>
            </h1>
          <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($site_slogan): ?>
          <div id="site-slogan"><?php print $site_slogan; ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div><!-- /#name-and-slogan -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

3) I cleared the cache

but then the module images don't appear and i got this error in the front page :

> Notice: Undefined variable: service in include()

i don't understand, what did I miss ?

Comment: In template.php, did you replace mytheme with the name of your theme in the theme_hook function, because the code you are showing didn't?
And the error message is pointing to the idea, that the variable is undefined aka your theme_on_the_web_image function is not seen by your theme.

Comment: Hi Laurent, yes i did : so now it's -> function zhongdao_on_the_web_image($variables) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after reading the module code :
The function zhongdao_on_the_web_image is for theming the rendering of your anchor tags. Not really what you want here, so you can remove it.

This module create a block (under admin > structure > bloc) that you can position anywhere in your theme regions, then up to you to style it differently with CSS.
But if you want to render the block content another solution is this one :
https://www.drupal.org/node/26502

Wich will translate to something like this :

```
    <?php if ($site_name || $site_slogan): ?>
          <div id="name-and-slogan">
          <div id="myidtomodifythecssafter"> 
<?php 
    $block = module_invoke('on_the_web', 'block_view', 0 /* might want to change depending of your block*/);
    print render($block['content']);
?>
</div>
            <?php if ($site_name): ?>
              <?php if ($title): ?>
                <div id="site-name"><strong>
                  <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home"><span><?php print $site_name; ?></span></a>
                </strong></div>
              <?php else: /* Use h1 when the content title is empty */ ?>
                <h1 id="site-name">
                  <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home"><span><?php print $site_name; ?></span></a>
                </h1>
              <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($site_slogan): ?>
              <div id="site-slogan"><?php print $site_slogan; ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </div><!-- /#name-and-slogan -->
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: perfect answer, merci Laurent ! it's work and the content does appear. I think I still have a lot of work to master Drupal. By the way, would you recommand me a good book about that (en français si possible) ?

Comment: No problem. I mainly use drupal.org and forums/blog so I will not be the best advice on books sorry.